# python: generate a list values with cumulative percent increments preferably using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to generate a list of values that are x% increment over base value. For example, if base value = 100, then generate additional values that are 5% increments over cumulative value.

The list would be [100, 105, 110.25, 115.75]

Is there a `numpy` routine I can use to do this? or any other quick way of doing this.

Comment: For such simple function a for loop is sufficient, create a function doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use [`np.cumprod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html)

```
import numpy as np

increment = 1.05  # is .05 because the increment is 5%
start = 100 # the start value

arr = np.repeat(increment, 4)
arr[0] = start

res = arr.cumprod()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[100.     105.     110.25   115.7625]
```

An alternative for building the array `arr` is to do:

```
arr = np.array([100, *np.repeat(increment, 3)])
```

Comment: Did the np.array work for you? How is the value of increment expressed?

Comment: @kms What did not work for you? I ran the code before posting it

Comment: `array([100.  ,   1.05,   1.05,   1.05])` <-- when I run `np.array` code.

Comment: If you mean the second approach, is just for building arr. You still need to apply cumprod

Comment: why is 5% expressed as 1.05 vs 0.05?

Comment: Because when you add a 5% increment you do 0.05 * 100 + 100, you factor out you get 100 * (1 + 0.05). Hope it helps